# PHP: Installing Libsodium to PHP v5.5

Tags: php, cryptography, libsodium, string-hashing

How to correctly install Libsodium with PHP verson 5.5.
I'm trying to follow the instruction on https://paragonie.com/book/pecl-libsodium/read/00-intro.md#installing-libsodium

Here are the steps I did:

1. Go to http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/libsodium/1.0.6/
2. Download "php_libsodium-1.0.6-5.5-nts-vc11-x64.zip" and extract files.
3. Copy "libsodium.dll" in my directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.5" where is "php.exe"
4. Copy "php_libsodium.dll" in my directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.5\ext"
5. Enable "extension=php_libsodium.dll" in php.ini file
6. Restart the server

But when I tested it by writing a simple PHP test file:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

// hash the password and return an ASCII string suitable for storage
$hash_str = sodium_crypto_pwhash_str(
        "mypassword",
        SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_OPSLIMIT_INTERACTIVE,
        SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_MEMLIMIT_INTERACTIVE
        );

echo "hash: " . $hash_str;
?>
```

The result page shows the error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function sodium_crypto_pwhash_str() in
>   C:\PHP\testLibsodium.php on line 7

The library Libsodium seems not installed because it doesn't know the function.
What things I need to do to install PHP Libsodium in PHP version 5.5?
Thank you very much.

Update: I've installed the X86 version as advised by @iann and run this code:

```
$storeInDatabase = \Sodium\crypto_pwhash_str(
        "safasfdwr32sfdfas234",
        SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_OPSLIMIT_INTERACTIVE,
        SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_MEMLIMIT_INTERACTIVE
        );
```

Now seems the function is being read but I'm getting an error:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant
>   SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_OPSLIMIT_INTERACTIVE - assumed
>   'SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_OPSLIMIT_INTERACTIVE'
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant
>   SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_MEMLIMIT_INTERACTIVE - assumed
>   'SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_MEMLIMIT_INTERACTIVE'
>
> Warning: Sodium\crypto_pwhash_str() expects parameter 2 to be long
>
> Catchable fatal error: crypto_pwhash_str(): invalid parameters

Does this mean that my libsodium is installed correctly, but why I'm getting an error? Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sodium_*` functions weren't in the global namespace until the library was moved into native PHP, in version 7.2. From [the manual](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/06/libsodium-quick-reference-quick-comparison-similar-functions-and-which-one-use):

> In PHP before 7.2 with libsodium from PECL, the functions below were defined in the Sodium name space. In PHP 7.2, the namespaces were dropped in favor of a sodium_ prefix (to conform to the PHP internal development standards).

So if you're installing from PECL, you need to use the previous function names. In your case:

```
$hash_str = \Sodium\crypto_pwhash_str(
...
```

Comment: Hi @iainn. Thank you it is helpful however I tried it but the same error: $hash_str = \Sodium\crypto_pwhash_str(
  "mypassword",
  SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_OPSLIMIT_INTERACTIVE,
  SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_MEMLIMIT_INTERACTIVE
  );

Comment: do I still need to install libsodium aside from PECL? Is it still not working.

Comment: @Jemru If the function still isn't registered under the other name, it sounds like the extension isn't loaded at all. Bit of a guess, but you mention that PHP is installed in **Program Files (x86)**, but that you've downloaded an extension labelled **x64**. You might be mixing 32 bit PHP with a 64 bit extension. Try [this one](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/libsodium/1.0.6/php_libsodium-1.0.6-5.5-nts-vc11-x86.zip)

Comment: Hi @iainn thank you i think the libsodium is installed. However I'm not sure why I'm getting an error on the function when I run an example above? Do I still need to install anything aside from "php_libsodium-1.0.6-5.5-nts-vc11-x86.zip"?

Comment: Easy mode: Add https://github.com/paragonie/sodium_compat via Composer and then the undefined constant issues will disappear.